# How to filter column by a single letter?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have an Excel sheet containing 7000 rows of data. The column that I need to do a filter on is full of job descriptions. Its a lot of words inside a single cell and looks like this:

[image]

What I'm trying to do is search through all these job postings for specific words like Python or SQL. The problem I am running into is one specific search: R. The R language is definitely here in many of the descriptions, but everything I try to filter by a single character doesn't seem to return all the correct cells.

I have tried using wildcards like `R~*`
I have also tried using `Begins with: R` and `Ends with:`(space)

Any idea the best way to go about this? Presumably the only way the language R would be displayed in a job description is by itself: "R" or in a sentence preceding a comma: "R,"

The source data can be found on Kaggle: https://www.kaggle.com/sl6149/data-scientist-job-market-in-the-us. I am trying to apply filters to the description column in the allData.csv (but change it to .xlsx to avoid issues).

FINAL EDIT: Was going to post this as an "Answer" and have it be accepted, but figured that might be disingenuous. I am moving on from trying to filter by `R`. I've tried almost every attempt posted here with inaccurate results. I am just going to exclude R from my report. Thanks everyone for the time and I really tried to get it to work.

Comment: The basic problem with the issue is long text has many spaces , since it's `Wrap text & Merge Cell` so to accommodated  lines Excel compromised with `white spaces` between, is the prime reason non of the suggested methods works 100% !!

Comment: I'd like an example of an inaccurate result with the solution I proposed.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you have Excel 2013+ with the `FILTERXML` function, you can use the Advanced Filter.

Construct an XML that divides on the spaces.
You may need to replace various punctuation with spaces also, and possibly also the line-feed character, if present (`CHAR(10)`)

Then look for `R` (and the comparison will be case-sensitive) and filter.

For example:

***Remove `,`, `.`, `!`, `?`*  and `Trim` to remove any extra spaces***

```
TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A8,","," "),"."," "),"!"," "),"?"," "))
```

***Create the xml with nodes defined by the spaces***

```
<t><s>" &SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A8,","," "),"."," "),"!"," "),"?"," "))," ","</s><s>") & "</s></t>"
```

Use `FILTERXML` with an `xpath` to return only the `R` and `NOT(ISERROR(…` to convert the result to either `TRUE` or `FALSE`

In the formulas, `A8` is the first cell with data to be tested.

**Criteria**

```
=NOT(ISERROR(FILTERXML("<t><s>" &SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A8,","," "),"."," "),"!"," "),"?"," "))," ","</s><s>") & "</s></t>","//s[.='R']")))
```

If you want to filter for multiple items at a time, merely repeat the criteria formula in adjacent rows,  changing the `[.='R']` portion.

eg:

```
=NOT(ISERROR(FILTERXML("<t><s>" &SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A8,","," "),"."," "),"!"," "),"?"," "))," ","</s><s>") & "</s></t>","//s[.='SQL']")))

=NOT(ISERROR(FILTERXML("<t><s>" &SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A8,","," "),"."," "),"!"," "),"?"," "))," ","</s><s>") & "</s></t>","//s[.='Python']")))
```

#### Before

[image]

#### After

[image]

**EDIT:**
*If you have an earlier version of Excel, with no `FILTERXML` function, you can use, for the criteria formula:*

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(EXACT("R",TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A8,","," "),"."," "),"!"," "),"?"," "))," ",REPT(" ",99)),seq_99,99)))))=1
```

where `seq_99` is a **named formula** that refers to:

```
=IF(ROW(INDEX($A$1:$A$65535,1,1):INDEX($A$1:$A$65535,255,1))=1,1,(ROW(INDEX($A$1:$A$65535,1,1):INDEX($A$1:$A$65535,255,1))-1)*99)
```

Answer (score 0):

Filtering for whole words is indeed not easy in Excel.

Easiest approach is probably to use regular expressions. 
As Excel doesn't support regular expressions, I use the free [RegEx Find/Replace](http://www.codedawn.com/excel-add-ins.php) add-in *(I'm not affiliated with it, just an enthusiast user)*.

You can add a helper column to check if R is included in a column, then filter by it.

`=RegExTest(A2,"(^|\W)R($|[^\w&])")`

How it works:

- `RegExTest` checks if pattern is found in text
- beginning of string, or any non-word character (white space, punctuation, ...): `(^|\W)`
- followed by `R`
- followed by any non-word character, non `&` or end of string `($|[^\w&])`

[image]

Comment: I'm really not well versed with Regex, so not even sure where to begin with that. There has to be a better way to do this. At this point I'm just considering ommiting `R` language and working with all the other skills I can easily find - SQL, Python, etc.

Comment: You just need to install the add-in, restart excel then insert the formula in a cell. Modify cell reference in the formula to the cell you want to filter on.

Comment: I managed to get the Regex formula working, thanks for the setup help. Unfortunately, based on the way the data is it is still not returning accurate findings. Its showing `TRUE` on a post without `R` and I think its flagging off something that looks like `R&amp;D `.

Comment: @Synik: thanks for the feedback, please see the updated answer, it's fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

If the number of different permutations of R is pretty manageable, you can manually build a formula to do this for you in a helper column. It wasn't really clear to me from your question what method of 'search' you're using right now (filter, ctrl+f, formula-based) so I'm not sure if this is the direction you're looking for, but it'll work.

Basically take advantage of the fact that `FIND` is natively case-sensitive and write a formula to find the different ways that 'R' might show up in a text string, then jam them together.

#### DEMO

[image]

`B2` formula:

`=NOT(ISERROR(FIND("R ",$A2)))`

`C2` formula:

`=NOT(ISERROR(FIND("R,",$A2)))`

`D2` formula:

`=NOT(ISERROR(FIND("R.",$A2)))`

`E2` formula:

`=NOT(ISERROR(FIND("R",$A2,LEN($A2))))`

#### RESULT

So if those possibilities are what you want to look for - a capital R followed by a space, comma, period or that is the last character in the cell - this formula in a helper column will give you that result.

`=NOT(ISERROR(FIND("R ",$A2)))+NOT(ISERROR(FIND("R,",$A2)))+NOT(ISERROR(FIND("R.",$A2)))+NOT(ISERROR(FIND("R",$A2,LEN($A2))))`

That will output 0 if every test is false, so you can filter that way.

Comment: Unfortunately this method is not working. I used your `"R "` (space) and `"R,"` (comma) method and they did return TRUE, so the formulas themselves are working. But when I verify manually to see if R is present by Copying the entire Cell and pasting it in Word to Advanced Search on "R", there are no instances of a single `R` by itself.

Comment: That's interesting. And curious. I'd love to see more information. What was triggering the `FIND("R ")` if not `"R "`?

Comment: I put the data source from Kaggle in my OP if you want to take a shot. I have moved on and ommited R cause I can't get a super clean filter like I can with other skills. I am using the allData file, just need to convert it to .xlsx - .csv messes everything up.

Answer (score -1):

*Simple `Custom Filter option`, solves the issue:*

[image]

**How it works:**

- Select required range along with Header.
- From **D**ata TAB, hit **F**ilter.
- Click Drop Down in City Column.
- From poped Menu, **T**ext Filters, pick **B**egins with or **C**ustom Filter.
- For Begins with text box write `D` or even `d` & finish with **O**k.

*Filter is case insensitive.*

[image]

*You get this:*

[image]

---

**Edited:**

[image]

**Situation 1:**

*Filter on `like`:*

[image]

- Use **T**ext Filters, pick `Contains` option.
- You may use specific text or combination of Wildcard like `*L*` or
  `*Ra*`.

Comment: While this does seem to somewhat work, this does not work for cases that have "R,"   (the letter with a comma).

Comment: @Synik,, in which Column you want to apply Filter `Position, Company or Description` !!

Comment: The Description column. The column has so much text, its not showing in the picture. I did manually look through them and found multiple that were not displaying filtered with your suggestion. All of them were R, (R with comma). 

Otherwise, your way works great, but I'm missing a lot of data if the comma is ignored.

Comment: Also if it helps, the source dataset is here: https://www.kaggle.com/sl6149/data-scientist-job-market-in-the-us.  I am using allData.

Comment: @Synik,, check the edited part !!

Comment: I'm sorry, I tried `Contains` with variations of `R,` but the specific ones I found manually with `R,` are not showing up. To clarify the comma is directly after the R, as normal when listing a set of skills. Are you able to specify what you entered into `Contains` to get all `R,` filters?

Comment: @Synik,, if it's the text `Please specify your need in language R` I've used `Begins` with option like `R~<sapce>` (R followed by ~ symbol then followed by SPACE) ,, Filters `R`,, look sometimes you need to adjust with TEXT or Characters around the TEXT!!

Comment: `R~ ,` with `Contains` Also did not work. In response to your "adjust text" comment, I had a great idea and removed all commas, but that also didn't show the 2 that I wrote down. I really have no idea why even that didn't work.....

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99864/discussion-between-rajesh-s-and-synik).